# How to create and store objects of a class in a list

Tags: python, list, class

I need to create instances from a single class and store the names in a list.

```
robot_list = []
for i in range (num_robots):
    robot_list.append('robot%s' %i)
```

This creates a list of the names I want to use as instances of a single class `Robot`. But they are of the `str` type so far. So I wrote this to change their type and assign the instances of the class to the names:

```
for i in robot_list:
    i = Robot()
```

Later when I want to use any of the elements in the list the program returns an `AttributeError` saying that the object is still a string.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
robot_list = [Robot() for i in xrange(num_robots)]
```

creates `num_robots` instances of the `Robot` class and stores them into `robot_list`.

If you want to "name" them, i.e. the constructor gets a string as parameter, use this:

```
robot_list = [Robot('robot{}'.format(i)) for i in xrange(num_robots)]
```

Comment: I think I would give them a serial number instead.  All of the robots which become sentient and try to take over the world have names ... Who ever heard of a robot 05XJ3DSA5 trying to take over the world?

Answer (score 1):

To add to other answers: your assignment does not work the way you expect it to.

```
for i in robots_list:
    i = Robot()
```

Will not save a robot object to each index in the list. It will create the object but instead of saving it to the index you wish, it will overwrite the temporary variable `i`. Thus all items in the list remain unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

You would need your robot class to take a string on initiallization (as its name). Note, when using the list of robots you would be acting on a robot object, not its name. However the robot would now have its name stored in the object.

```
class Robot():
    def __init__(roboName = ''):
        self.name = roboName

    # all other class methods after this

if __name__ == '__main__'
    robot_list = []
    for i in xrange (num_robots):
        robo_name = 'robot%s' % i
        robot_list.append(Robot(robo_name))
```